# Add html attribute to string with javascript replace (regexp)

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to add a **ng-click** attribute to a IMG tag present in a string, using String.replace.

Example:

```js
<p>Test1</p>
<p>
  <img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/a4cafaf13aabb97b041a50ae55c7bb6d331a7cc4.jpg">
  Foto1
</p>
<p>
  <img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/c5a7fc84d8f552d208e5ee0e0cbcecc0d547b441.jpg" style="width: 300px;">
</p>
```

Needs to be converted to:

```
<p>Test1</p>
<p>
  <img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/a4cafaf13aabb97b041a50ae55c7bb6d331a7cc4.jpg" ng-click="openModal('http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/a4cafaf13aabb97b041a50ae55c7bb6d331a7cc4.jpg')">
  Foto1
</p>
<p>
  <img class="fr-dib fr-draggable" src="http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/c5a7fc84d8f552d208e5ee0e0cbcecc0d547b441.jpg" ng-click="openModal('http://admin.fsn.dev/uploads/c5a7fc84d8f552d208e5ee0e0cbcecc0d547b441.jpg')" style="width: 300px;">
</p>
```

Any suggestion?

I tried with this but no luck :(

```js
data = data.replace(/<img(.*)src="(.*)"(.*)>/ig,'<img $1 src="$2" ng-click="openModal(\'$2\')" $3')
```

Comment: you are heading the wrong solution to hook angular directive markup to the rendered dom.

Comment: I know that this is not extremely correct, but I need to attach this tag to the images. The html is created from an external wysiwyg editor and I need to attach an event to zoom the images on click.

Comment: Alternatively , you can use JQuery instead of angularJs in this case, because angluarJs needs its directive to work on the dom, while Jquery is flexible by simply using selectors.